# How to edit and update according to user's choice in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to edit the selected item from the `main view` list in a separate html view, so when the `save button` is clicked the changes are reflected to the list in the `main view`.Im my edit I have used `title`,`description`,`from` and `to` dates to edit.I got struck with an idea here, that is, what if the user only wants to edit any one of the four details and save the rest details the same, I tried it with the `ng-model` but it could read only the edited details but not the already existing one. So I'm looking for a help in this.

Html:

```
<div align="center">
            Title
            <input type="text" ng-model="selectInput.Title">
            Offer:
            <input type="text" ng-model="selectInput.data.description">
            Valid from:
            <input type="date" ng-click="FromDate()" ng-model="frDate">
            <br> Valid till:
            <input type="date" ng-click="ToDate()" ng-model="toDate" />
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button ng-click='SaveEdit($index)' ng-model="editSave"> Save</button>
```

controller:

```
   $scope.items = [];
  $rootScope.couponList = [{ Title: "Fruit Export Details" data: {description: "consume soon product", Fromdate: "2016-09-09", Todate: "2016-09-18"}},
  {Title: "Vegetables Export Details",  data:{description: "consume soon product", Fromldate: "2016-11-09", Todate: "2016-10-19"}},
  { CouponTitle: "Saviours",data:{description: "storable", Fromldate: "2016-09-10", Todate: "2016-10-09"}}];

  $scope.select_item = function (key) {
    //alert(key);
    $scope.items.push(key);

  }
    $scope.SaveEdit=function(){
           $scope.Title=$scope.selectInput.data.Title;
        $scope.description=$scope.selectedInput.data.description;
        $scope.Fromdate=$scope.selectInput.data.Fromdate;
        $scope.Todate=$scope.selectInput.data.Todate;
      }
      $state.go('app.WashType');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are problem is mismatching of ng-model names in your controller

HTML (**MODIFIED**)

```
 <div align="center">
                Title
<!-- <input type="text" ng-model="selectInput.Title"> -->
                <input type="text" ng-model="$scope.selectInput.data.Title">
                Offer:
                <input type="text" ng-model="$scope.selectedInput.data.description">
                Valid from:
<!-- <input type="date" ng-click="FromDate()" ng-model="frDate">-->
                <input type="date" ng-click="FromDate()" ng-model="$scope.selectInput.data.Fromdate">
                <br> Valid till:
<!-- <input type="date" ng-click="ToDate()" ng-model="toDate" /> -->
                <input type="date" ng-click="ToDate()" ng-model="$scope.selectInput.data.Todate" />
            </div>
            <hr>
            <button ng-click='SaveEdit($index)' ng-model="editSave"> Save</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.items = [];
  $rootScope.couponList = [{ Title: "Fruit Export Details" data: {description: "consume soon product", Fromdate: "2016-09-09", Todate: "2016-09-18"}},
  {Title: "Vegetables Export Details",  data:{description: "consume soon product", Fromldate: "2016-11-09", Todate: "2016-10-19"}},
  { CouponTitle: "Saviours",data:{description: "storable", Fromldate: "2016-09-10", Todate: "2016-10-09"}}];

  $scope.select_item = function (key) {
    //alert(key);
    $scope.items.push(key);

  }
    $scope.SaveEdit=function(){
           $scope.Title=$scope.selectInput.data.Title;
        $scope.description=$scope.selectedInput.data.description;
        $scope.Fromdate=$scope.selectInput.data.Fromdate;
        $scope.Todate=$scope.selectInput.data.Todate;
      }
      $state.go('app.WashType');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model values don't line up with what you're using in the controller.

The first two set a property on the `selectInput` property of the $scope and the `data` property on the `selectInput` property on the scope, but $scope never seems to get an object `selectInput` assigned to it, let along it having a `data` property.

In your controller you should add during initialization:

```
$scope.selectInput = {data:null};
```

The third and fourth fields have names that don't line up at all with the scope.

**HTML**

```
<div align="center">
    Title
    <input type="text" ng-model="selectInput.data.Title">
    Offer:
    <input type="text" ng-model="selectInput.data.Description">
    Valid from:
    <input type="date" ng-click="FromDate()" ng-model="selectInput.data.FromDate">
    <br> 
    Valid till:
    <input type="date" ng-click="ToDate()" ng-model="selectInput.data.ToDate" />
</div>
<hr>
<button ng-click='SaveEdit()'> Save</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.items = [];
$rootScope.couponList = [...items here...];

$scope.select_item = function (key) {
    //alert(key);
    $scope.items.push(key);
}

$scope.SaveEdit = function(){
    // Do stuff with
    // $scope.selectInput.data.Title;
    // $scope.selectInput.data.Description;
    // $scope.selectInput.data.FromDate;
    // $scope.selectInput.data.ToDate;
}
```